# How to resolve class receipt and class ReceiptStore in In-app-non renewable subscription

Tags: codenameone

I was following the tutorial  Non-Renewable subscriptio on the blog in CN1 website.

I was unable to run the code because of receipt class and receiptstore class.

```
import com.codename1.payment.Receipt;
import com.codename1.payment.ReceiptStore;
```

I did't know what is wrong with the two lines of code above. Pls I need someone to tell me what am missing here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These classes were just added recently.  Try updating your codenameone plugin.  I think those classes should be there in the latest.

Comment: Not the plugin the libraries... Right click project. Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> Basics -> Update Client Libs